# Swift: initialising an instance method using class initialiser and 'let'. Is it correct?

Tags: swift, initialization, let, instance-method

With this simplified `Unit` class, I have an **unset method called** `myMethod` which is initialised when a new instance is created.

```
typealias Converter = (input: Double) -> Double

class Unit {
    let name: String
    let myMethod: Converter

    init(name: String, method: Converter) {
        self.name = name
        self.myMethod = method
    }
}
```

To create an instance of this class I **attach a `Converter` type function** (`celsiusToKelvin()`) in the initialisation as below:

```
func celsiusToKelvin(input: Double) -> Double { return input + 273.15 }

let celsius = Unit(name: "Celsius", method: celsiusToKelvin)
```

Now I can use the `celsius.myMethod()` the same as any instance method, even though I didn't define it as a `func` in the `Unit` class.

**Questions:**

**1)** Is this a valid approach for adding methods to particular instances of a class?

**2)** Can it also be done for a `struct`?

**3)** Are there other (better/safer) ways to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: This is completely valid but with several comments: 1. calling things `method` is pretty bad, just call it `converter`. 2. Usually people won't pass `func`, they will pass a closure directly. 3. It can be easily used on structs, even on constant strucs. However, depending on your architecture, it could be more readable to make every unit as a subclass instead of generating them dynamically.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! yeah I just called it `method` here to make it clear in the class definition. If I used subclasses, would i have to make instances before I can call their methods?

Comment: That really depends on how you do it. You can have class methods.